# “Pureness of the ocean”

Tags: semantics

“Pure” should modify words indicating color.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pure

Then, I wonder, for example, to express pureness of blue of the ocean, “pureness of the ocean” doesn’t work, and only “pureness of blue” works.

Comment: What makes you think that **pure** should modify words indicating colour? That is pure nonsense! Anyhow, no colours are pure anything, although people might well describe them as such.

Comment: @Ronald Sole I mean “if ‘pure’ should be confined to them,” it’s kind of proposition.

Comment: It's a very bad hypothesis. I suspect that it will not be treated kindly. **Pure** is used mainly to mean not contaminated by or mixed with any other element. But metaphorically it can be used in a huge variety of contexts - pure breed, pure pleasure, pure water.

Comment: @Ronald Sole What I wonder about is this, can “pureness of the ocean” refer to pureness of blue colour of the ocean?

Comment: Yes, if that's what the writer/speaker intends. Whether the reader/listener will understand it as such is another matter.

Comment: @Ronald Sole Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but your assumption that pure can only modify color is incorrect. In the future, doing more research will help you avoid being spanked like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure can modify words indicting that it is not mixed with something else

> "Pure cotton" "pure water"

Particularly, not mixed with something harmful

> "Pure air"

And it can be metaphorical

> "pure horror", "pure hell"

***When*** it is applied to a colour word, it means an unmixed and intense form of that colour

> "pure white" (#FFFFFF the colour of snow) "pure black" (#000000 the colour of soot) "pure blue" (probably the colour of ultramarine paint, although this one is more ambiguous, in HTML terms it is #0000FF)

"The ocean" is not a colour word, so "pureness (or purity?) of the ocean" would refer probably to sense 1 or 2 (not mixed with anything harmful) or perhaps sense 3 (a metaphor for the effect of the ocean on your spirit?)